# creating custom annotation and using it in java?

Tags: java, annotations, java-ee-7

I have written below the Custom Annotation.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();

}
```

and am using the annotation as below.

```
@MyAnnotation("someValue")
public void someMethod(){


}
```

above code is working fine without any issues. 
But in the annotation class, **value()** method name i have to reanme. Can i do as below?

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MyAnnotation {

        String name();

    }
```

I tried doing but eclipse is giving the compilation error.

```
- The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
     MyAnnotation
    - The annotation @MyAnnotation must define the attribute 
     name
```

Any reason?

Comment: As i m not getting any error.so please post your error too?

Comment: Prateek, i edited my question...

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this :

```
@MyAnnotation(name="someValue")
public void someMethod(){


}
```

because by default annotation has value method so if you specify like this

```
@MyAnnotation("someValue")
    public void someMethod(){


    }
```

it will by default take it as `value="someValue"`

Comment: My pleasure.I will try to find out some resource for you and provide you with the link.